# Connections between circuit complexity and Unique Games Conjecture?

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, approximation, circuits

Circuit complexity has connections to many questions in complexity theory.
For a couple examples, Ryan Williams shared some in [a recent talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S8fKlR28Go) and Section 3 of [these notes](https://web.stanford.edu/~rrwill/week1.pdf) gives simple relations to $\mathbf{P}$ vs. $\mathbf{NP}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ vs. $\mathbf{BPP}$.
More can be found in the textbook [*Boolean Function Complexity*](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642245077).
On the other hand, the Unique Games Conjecture has been linked to a wide range of computational problems and areas of applied mathematics; see e.g. [this talk](https://youtu.be/iX2MyUBvZJk?t=1265) or this [survey of Khot](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~khot/papers/UGCSurvey.pdf).

What I'm wondering is, are there strong connections known between circuit complexity and hardness of approximation, specifically the Unique Games Conjecture?
If so, what are they?